# How to convert imperial to metric units in api?

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

How do i convert this API results from imperial to metric units. Below is the code for fetch api.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + inputValue.value + '&APPID=501cd47da792c61ec790cdbc6913fced')
    .then(Response => Response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
})
```

Comment: Append `&units=metric`

Answer (score 1):

Like @Orkhan Alikhanov said in the comment, you can add the unit argument to metric on the url for this API. Like this :

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  fetch('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + inputValue.value + '&units=metric&APPID=501cd47da792c61ec790cdbc6913fced')
    .then(Response => Response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
})
```